# How do I wire up a client Javascript function call when creating a new CheckBox in my codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, dynamic-controls

In my ASP.NET page's code behind I'm creating a checkbox on the fly:

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
```

But I want the new checkbox to call a client function instead of posting back. I would expect to be able to do something like this:

```
cb.OnClientClick = "Javascript:MyClientFunction();";
```

But that doesn't exist. How do I wire it up on the fly like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
cb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Javascript:MyClientFunction();");
```

Answer (score 1):

On code behind you can use `Attributes.Add("onclick", "Javascript:MyClientFunction();")`